# Are 'My Site' pages available on all licensing levels for SP 2010?

Tags: 2010, licensing

do I need to purchase the enterprise version of SharePoint 2010 to have the My Site pages available?  Or are these functions available at all license levels?  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The My sites comes with standard and Enterprise SharePoint 2010.
Please follow the link below
http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/buy/pages/editions-comparison.aspx
Look for My profile.My profiles is not included in SharePoint foundation Server.But it is in Standard edition and Enterprise edition.Hope this helps

Comment: Aaaaand.. thank you for googling that for me :)  Seriously, had trouble finding that for some reason, appreciate the help!

Comment: No Probs, glad i was able to help!:)